# Laravel Missing required parameters for Route:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We are getting a weird error and I've looked at our Git history and no one has touched this controller and routes belonging to them in several months.

We have a form that takes the `GET` `Request` data from a page and passes them from Step 1 to Step 2. So the variables are inserted into the URL such as `/refer/step_2?name='john'&phone="9999999999"` etc.

Error:

`Missing required parameters for [Route: step_2] [URI: refer/step/2].`

Step 2 (Post Request):

```
/**
 * Validates data from step and moves on to step 2.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function step1_request(Request $request) {
    // Remove any additional characters from the lead phone number.
    $request['phone'] = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $request->phone);
    $request->merge(['phone' => $request['phone']]);

    $validate = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|digits:10'
    ];

    $validationErrorMessages = [
        'phone.digits' => 'The phone number must be 10 digits. No spacing, dashes, or special characters.'
    ];

    $validateData = $request->validate($validate, $validationErrorMessages);

    //dd returns fine here.. includes the request data.
    return redirect()->route('step_2', $request); // <- Error happens here. Missing required parameters for [Route: step_2] 
}
```

Step 2 (blade)

```
/**
 * Returns a view to confirm the output from step 1.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function step_2(Request $request) {
    .....
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::prefix('refer')->group(function () {
    // Step 1
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step_1', 'as' => 'step_1']);
    Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step1_request']);
    // Step 2
    Route::get('step/2', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step_2', 'as' => 'step_2']);
    Route::post('/step/2', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step2_request']);
    // Step 3 
    Route::get('step/3', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step3', 'as' => 'step_3']);
    Route::post('step/3', ['uses' => 'ReferController@step3_request']);
});
```

Just to reiterate -- this has worked for months with no problems. I've cleared a blank database, and reset the git head to the initial commit of when we created this, and I'm still getting the same error. Has anything updated as far as Laravel, etc?

Comment: check for route duplication below

Comment: @SergeyShuryakov Good suggestion but all is good there. No duplications.

Comment: ok. That's weird. Did you try to change route to `Route::get('step/2', 'ReferController@step_2')->name('step_2');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by changing:
`return redirect()->route('step_2', $request)`

to:
`return redirect()->route('step_2', $request->all())`

This seems to be an app breaking bug in Laravel 5.6 from a recent small patch.

Comment: what recent small patch are you referring to?

Comment: In Laravel 6.10 the problem is still here.